# Is kuroneko from Oreimo considered dandere?

Tags: oreimo

[image: Kuroneko]

from Urban dictionary,

Dandere

> A dandere is a character archtype that entails someone being quiet
>   which is usually associated with shyness. "Dan" comes from the word
>   "danmari" which means silent and taciturn. "Dere" means to become
>   "lovey dovey"
>
> Not to be confused with Kuudere which is a cool person that becomes
>   lovey dovey. They are very similar in appearence and possibly
>   behavior, but their underlying character reasoning is different. Being
>   silent for the sake of being silent vs being cool

I have a problem placing her as a dandere because she sometimes acts playful as the image above (not antisocial). Am I correct considering her dandere ?

Comment: I never get tired of that image since it gets re-posted in the chat room here alot of the time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, she can be considered a [**Dandere**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Dandere) character.

> A dandere character is one who is normally quiet and silent, possibly to the point of coming across as emotionless at times, but will suddenly become talkative and sweet and cute when alone with the right person if they manage to push the right button to get them to pour their heart out, revealing that they're actually just shy.
>
> A dandere will be more or less a normal person, but, will not talk unless spoken to/required to. They will avoid talking because of their shyness, but if need be, they will speak. Also, a dandere tends to feel more power in numbers. If they're with a group that they're comfortable with, then the shyness factor of said dandere will very likely decrease if another, unfamiliar person is introduced at that time.

- At the first otaku meeting of **Kirino**, **Ruri** (a.k.a. **Kuroneko**) was silent and passed her time with her cell phone, but later when **Saori** introduced them to each other, Ruri was talking (quarreling) with Kirino.
- Ruri was comfortable with **Kyosuke**. She was talking normally with him and

  > confessed her love to Kyosuke.
- She also talks and enjoy herself when she is with members of Saori's circle and with school club.

These are, however, only some examples of her behavior. Throughout the entire series, there are many occasions where her character matches the description of a Dandere as stated above.

Answer (score -2):

She should be considered kudere because of her lack of emotion...most of the time

Comment: "Lack of emotion" is not a term I'd ever think appropriate to describe Kuroneko. The first time she and Kirino get in a room together, they get in a fight, with Kuroneko fighting just as passionately as Kirino. They're not fire and ice; they're a red flame and a blue flame, each as hot as the other.